# How to perform a spark join if any (not all) conditions are met

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe%20join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) states that a join operation can be performed as the following:

```
cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age]
df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
```

Which will join successfully the rows where both the name and the age column match. I am trying to perform the same join but on the condition that either the name or the age column matches.

I've tried:

```
df.join(import_df, df.col1 == import_df.colA | df.col2 == import_df.colB , how="left")
```

But that gives me an error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: Put the conditions between parenthesis. The operator "|" has precedence over "=="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap join conditions in **brackets** **`()`** then use **or** **`|`** operator in the join.

```
df.join(import_df, (df.col1 == import_df.colA) | (df.col2 == import_df.colB) , "left")
```

**`Using cond variable:`**

```
cond=[(df.col1 == import_df.colA) | (df.col2 == import_df.colB)]
df.join(import_df, cond, "left").show()
```